# left join to default values table

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of process that needs to run every day, ofter thy run the write to DB if the success or failed,
its is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE
        process(name text, status text, reason text);

INSERT INTO
    process
VALUES
    ('run','OK',''),
    ('stop','ERROR','exception');
```

and I have another table that has the list of all the processes that need to run.

```
 CREATE TABLE
    full_process(name text, status text, reason text);


INSERT INTO 
    full_process 
VALUES
    ('run','ERROR','script didnt run'),
    ('stop','ERROR','script didnt run'),
    ('report','ERROR','script didnt run');
```

I want to left join them so il get all the process that runs from `process` table and the ones that didn't run to get the default value from the `full_process` table
I tried this

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM
    process as a
LEFT JOIN full_process as b ON a.name = b.name;
```

but I'm getting only the default value from the `full_process` table, and when I'm trying the opposite I'm getting only the ones from `process` table

Comment: What ORM or database library are you using? Notice that your result contains multiple columns with the same name, which is probably not optimal. Try to select `b.status AS default_status` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the solution is this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.status,
b.reason 
FROM full_process as a
    LEFT JOIN process as b 
        ON a.name = b.name
```

and if I don't want to have `null` in the table

```
SELECT a.name,
    COALESCE(b.status, 'ERROR') AS statusת
    COALESCE(b.reason, 'RECORD MISSING') AS reason
FROM full_process as a
    LEFT JOIN process as b 
        ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Notice this will give `NULL` instead of the default value for rows that are not in the `process` table as well

Comment: I know, I have a case for that. Il update my answer

Comment: Ah. You can simplify that to `COALESCE(b.reason, 'RECORD MISSING') AS reason` btw

Comment: @Bergi I didn't know about that function, it much more cleaner tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM
    process as a
FULL OUTER JOIN full_process as b ON a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: no, I'm looking for left join, I want all the row from  `process` and what not in `process` take from `full_process`